# No longer able to retrieve pip login credentials in the Connect to Feed view

Tags: python, pip, azure-devops

In the Artifacts > Connect to Feed view, there used to be a way to get the pip username and password. Now this has been removed and there is an instruction get an artifacts keyring.

Is there any way to retrieve the pip password or go back to the old view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to retrieve the pip password or go back to the old
>   view?

Sorry but I'm afraid the answer is Negative.

As I know, it's not supported to go back to old view unless it's a preview features(pip view is not preview features).

I used these related Rest-APIs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifacts/feed%20%20management/get%20feed?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) and find that no info about `UserName` and `Password` would be returned. I'm afraid it's impossible to retrieve the pip password now.

Answer (score 0):

The username can be anything, and the password is an active PAT with access to Artifacts.